# Expression Engine - passing multiple categories as URL segments

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to create a product filter with deep-linking capability.  Essentially, I want the user to be able to filter my product list on multiple categories and have the URL reflect the filtering they've done.

So it would start as:

www.site.com/products/

My first level of category filtering already works.  So I can use EE's regular handling of URL segments to get to my first level of filtering.  For instance:

www.site.com/products/leatherthongs

Returns a filtered subset showing only a spectacular collection of leather thongs.  But now I want the user to be able to filter on another category - color for instance.  This is where stuff stops working.

EE's way of handling multiple categories inside templates (with ampersands or pipes) doesn't work in the URL:

www.site.com/products/leatherthongs&red

Nor does any variation that I've tried.

My next move is to create a simple raw PHP method that can capture regular querystring parameters and then inject them into the {entries} tag before rendering.  Not very difficult, but quite ugly.  I would love to know if there is a way to handle multiple categories in the URL natively.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Low's [Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) add-on? I'm not sure how complex you want to make this but it seems that you could specify something in your channel:entries loop like `categories='{segment_2){if segment_3}|{segment_3_category_id}{/if}'`

This exact syntax is untested but I have had success in the past with a similar solution.